# Why do we use expectation in reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

In reinforcement learning we use lot of expectations, what's the logic behind them?

Like in reward function, we use expected return instead of return, in value functions V and action-value functions Q we use expectation. Almost every-term in reinforcement learning is written in the form of expectation. Why?

Why do we use expectations?